# tidyjson could not find function "spread_all"

Tags: json

I wanted to follow the example [here](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson) but I got this message:

Error in function_list[k] : could not find function "spread_all"

Why? What am I doing wrong? Here's my session info
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
locale:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
```

Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the new version of `tidyjson` has unfortunately not yet been released to CRAN.  That is something that I hope will happen soon!

In any case, you can always use the most recent development version (the version that includes `spread_all` and the version that supports the example that you found) with:

```
devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')
library(tidyjson)

'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' %>% spread_all()
```